# list all the ways 4 random numbers (0-9) can equal 10 (using any operator +,-,*,/)

Tags: python, math, operators

I would like to write a program that takes 4 single digit numbers as an input (or one 4 digit number spliced) and find the different ways it can be manipulated (+,-,*,/) to equal 10.

Some examples would be:

1. 1548: 8-4+1+5 = 10
2. 2331: 3*3+2-1 = 10
3. 2293: (9-3)*2-2 = 10

You are required to use every digit but you can only use them once.

So in example 3 you would not be able to do 3-2+9 = 10 since you did not use the 6
and in example 2 you cannot do 3+3+3+1 = 10 since you can only use two 3's

To tackle this problem I started by finding each way this sequence of numbers could be ordered.
so 4 for loops (a,b,c,d) and skipping when a,b,c or d are equal.

However, I am unsure how to then place these numbers with different basic operators to cover all the possible permutations.

In my head I would write a function findSolution(x1,x2,x3,x4) that returns a list of strings similar to this => "(x1+x2)/x3*x4"

**----EDIT----**

Requested code:

```
for a in range(1,5):
  for b in range(1,5):
    if a != b:
      for c in range(1,5):
        if a != b and a != c and b != c:
          for d in range(1,5):
            if a != b and a != c and b != c and a != d and b != d and c != d:
              print(str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d))
```

This prints out what I think are all the unique ways you can order the digits:
1234,1243,1324,1342,1423,1432,2134,2143,2314,2341,2413,2431,3124,3142,3214,3241,3412,3421,4123,4132,4213,4231,4312,4321

---

**----UPDATE----**

I have adapted the answer below by FrustratedDeveloper to get the following (mainly including the use of parentheses):

```
from itertools import product
from itertools import permutations

#generates all permutations for ordering the operations of length 3
operatorList = list(product(['+','-','*','/'], repeat = 3))

#num='5461'
#num='9989'
#num='7374'
num='1234'

#gets a list of all the permutations for ordering the numbers
operandList=list(permutations(num,4))

#init an empty set
result=set()

#steps through the operation permutations in operator list
for opertion in operatorList:
  #steps through the number permutations
  for operand in operandList:
    #creates a string using the values in the permutations
    strings=set()
    #(a,b,c,d)
    evlStr1=operand[0]+opertion[0]+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]
    strings.add(evlStr1)
    #((a,b),c,d)
    evlStr2="("+operand[0]+opertion[0]+operand[1]+")"+opertion[1]+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]
    strings.add(evlStr2)
    #(a,(b,c),d)
    evlStr3=operand[0]+opertion[0]+"("+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+")"+opertion[2]+operand[3]
    strings.add(evlStr3)
    #(a,b,(c,d))
    evlStr4=operand[0]+opertion[0]+operand[1]+opertion[1]+"("+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]+")"
    strings.add(evlStr4)
    #((a,b),(c,d))
    evlStr5="("+operand[0]+opertion[0]+operand[1]+")"+opertion[1]+"("+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]+")"
    strings.add(evlStr5)
    #((a,b,c),d)
    evlStr6="("+operand[0]+opertion[0]+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+")"+opertion[2]+operand[3]
    strings.add(evlStr6)
    #(a,(b,c,d))
    evlStr7=operand[0]+opertion[0]+"("+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]+")"
    strings.add(evlStr7)
    #(((a,b),c),d)
    evlStr8=operand[0]+opertion[0]+"("+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]+")"
    strings.add(evlStr8)
    #((a,(b,c)),d)
    evlStr9="("+operand[0]+opertion[0]+"("+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+")"+")"+opertion[2]+operand[3]
    strings.add(evlStr9)
    #(a,(b,(c,d))
    evlStr10=operand[0]+opertion[0]+"("+operand[1]+opertion[1]+"("+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]+")"+")"
    strings.add(evlStr10)
    #(a,((b,c),d)
    evlStr11=operand[0]+opertion[0]+"("+"("+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+")"+opertion[2]+operand[3]+")"
    strings.add(evlStr11)
    for string in strings:
      try:
        if eval(string)==10:
          result.add(string)
      except ZeroDivisionError:
          x=1
          #print("You can't divide by zero: " + string)

#for i in result:
  #print (i)
print("Solution count: " + str(len(result)))
print(list(result)[0])
```

Comment: please show your attempt as code a basic solution in itself is fine.

Comment: Your last example equals 6, not 10. (9-3)*2-6 = 6 * 2 - 6 = 12 - 6 = 6. The inclusion of parentheses will increase the complexity of your solution, e.g. (9-3)*2-6, (9-3*2)-6, 9-(3*2)-6, 9-(3*2-6), 9-3*(2-6), ...

Comment: @Alexander This has been fixed. and I agree. However parentheses are required. This is the part I was stuck on

Comment: @AlbinPaul My attempt was as mentioned 4 for loops. I didn't know how to proceed after this. I didn't think this would be useful to anyone. however, i have added the code you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try below approach Using [product](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-all-possible-n-combination-tuples/) , [permutations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/) and [eval](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/eval/)

However I m not claim that it's perfect answer but may near to solution :

```
# cook your code here
from itertools import product
from itertools import permutations
operatorList = list(product(['+','-','*','/'], repeat = 3))
ip=['1541','2331','2293']
#operandList=list(permutations(['2','3','3','1'],4))
result=set()
for opertion in operatorList:
  for i in ip:
    operandList=list(permutations(i,4))
    for operand in operandList:
        evlStr=operand[0]+opertion[0]+operand[1]+opertion[1]+operand[2]+opertion[2]+operand[3]
        if eval(evlStr)==10:
           result.add(evlStr)
for i in result:
  print (i)
```

[demo](https://repl.it/languages/python3)